# How to scroll an overlay sidebar only without scrolling the whole page

Tags: css, vue.js, scroll

On the page, there is a sidebar overlay on the main content. Both the sidebar and the main content should be scrollable. But when the sidebar scrolls to the bottom, the main content continues to scroll. How to prevent the main content from scrolling when the mouse is scrolling the sidebar? In other words, the sidebar and the main content should scroll independently.

Other than adding listeners to the mouseover or scroll event, is there any method that uses CSS only to solve the issue?

The main structure of the page is like this and a demo to illustrate my issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoZqzg

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Vue, you can use vue-scroll-stop (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll-stop)

```
npm i --save vue-scroll-stop
```

Import in main.js:

```
import VueScrollStop from 'vue-scroll-stop'
Vue.use(VueScrollStop)
```

And use it on your HTML tag:

```
<div v-scroll-stop></div>
```

Fixed demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m3da7Lp0/2/

Answer (score 0):

using CSS
i add content class inside sidebar

```
<style>
 .sidebar .content {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      min-height: 500px;
 }
</style>

<div class="sidebar">
 <div class="content">

<p>facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna</p>
<p>facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna</p>
<p>facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna</p>
<p>facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna</p>
<p>facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna</p>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: In your answer, the main content height is so large that it won't scroll at any time. Would you try to reduce the height of the window? I tried your method but the issue still exists.